# Using RegReplace in Sublime Text 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

Install the RegReplace plugins in Sublime Text 3 to make several changes in a document. Following the documentation create the rules of search and substitution, but I present several problems to which I can not find the solution.
These are the rules created.

```
{
    "format": "3.0",
    "replacements":
    {

        "cambio_afiliacion":
        {
            "find": "\\affil{([0-9,]*)}",
            "replace": "<sup>\\1</sup>",
            "greedy": true,
            "greedy_scope": true
        },

        "cambio_section":
        {
            "find": "\\section{(.+?)}",
            "replace": "<h3>\\1</h3>",
            "greedy": true,
            "greedy_scope": true
        },

        "cambio_href":
        {
            "find": "\\href{(.+?)}{(.+?)}",
            "replace": "<a href=\"\\1\">\\2</a>",
            "greedy": true,
            "greedy_scope": true
        },

    }
}
```

And this is the shortcut you create to run it in Default.sublime-keymap

```
{   
        "keys": ["ctrl+alt+j"],
        "command": "reg_replace",
        "args": {
            "replacements": [
                                "cambio_afiliacion",
                                "cambio_href",
                                "cambio_section",
        ],
            "find_only":false,
        }
    },
```

The text of the document to be edited is as follows

```
 \href{google.com}{google.com}

 Ivonne Narváez Zurita\affil{1}*

 \section{Introducción}
```

When you execute the shortcut you only make the changes in this way

```
\<a href="google.com">google.com</a>

 Ivonne Narváez Zurita\affil{1}*

 \section{Introducción}
```

and should get this result

```
<a href="google.com">google.com</a>
Ivonne Narváez Zurita<sup>1</sup>*
<h3>Introducción</h3>
```

I can not find where the error can be that does not execute all the replacements and does not perform them in the correct way as shown in the `\href` where I get `\<a>`.

Answer (score 2):

Since patterns are being defined in JSON strings in the settings, you have to remember to define escapes properly. `\\a` Will be the same as `\a` which is a special regex escape. If you want a literal `\`, you have to escape the escape `\\\\a`. It's an additional level of indirection. You have to account for JSON string escapes, **and** regex pattern escapes. It's annoying, but but just the way it is when using the Sublime settings.

```
        "cambio_afiliacion":
        {
            "find": "\\\\affil{([0-9,]*)}",
            "replace": "<sup>\\1</sup>",
            "greedy": true,
            "greedy_scope": true
        },

        "cambio_section":
        {
            "find": "\\\\section{(.+?)}",
            "replace": "<h3>\\1</h3>",
            "greedy": true,
            "greedy_scope": true
        },

        "cambio_href":
        {
            "find": "\\\\href{(.+?)}{(.+?)}",
            "replace": "<a href=\"\\1\">\\2</a>",
            "greedy": true,
            "greedy_scope": true
        },
```